# org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleName.setIdentifier Caused by: IllegalArgumentException Jibx?

Tags: java, eclipse, xsd, jibx

Hi i am new XSD and jibx world, i am facing very strange issue where while generating jibx classes for XSD i am getting following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleName.setIdentifier (SimpleName.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST.newSimpleName (AST.java:1303)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.ClassBuilder.createNormalMethodCall (ClassBuilder.java:588)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.StructureClassHolder.addRepeatedProperty (StructureClassHolder.java:1055)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.StructureClassHolder.addToClass (StructureClassHolder.java:1485)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.StructureClassHolder.addToClass (StructureClassHolder.java:1478)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.StructureClassHolder.addToClass (StructureClassHolder.java:1478)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.StructureClassHolder.generate (StructureClassHolder.java:2146)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.PackageHolder.generate (PackageHolder.java:210)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.PackageHolder.generate (PackageHolder.java:227)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen.buildDataModel (CodeGen.java:1572)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen.generate (CodeGen.java:1781)
    at org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen.main (CodeGen.java:2206)
    at org.jibx.maven.AbstractCodeGenMojo.execute (AbstractCodeGenMojo.java:271)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I did debug jibx maven plugin found following observations

[image]

Line number 191 is where the exception is been thrown... here is the values

> identifier : TelecommunicationAddressUse.toString length : 36
> scanner.currentPosition : 27

```
  <xs:simpleType name="TelecommunicationAddressUse">
      <xs:restriction base="cs">
         <xs:enumeration value="BAD"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="CONF"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="H"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="HP"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="HV"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="TMP"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="WP"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="DIR"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="PUB"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="AS"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="EC"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="MC"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="PG"/>
      </xs:restriction>    </xs:simpleType>
```

Now question is do i need to do changes in XSD to generate jibx classes or what i need to do for solving this issue

Comment: What version of Eclipse? That code is substantially different in the current Eclipse 2021-03.

Comment: The code is throwing an exception because it has been given an invalid identifier by the jibx code (something that does not conform to the rules for a Java 'simple name').

Comment: @greg-449 Do you want me to try in different eclipse ??

Comment: The latest version of Eclipse includes exactly what the invalid name is in the exception which may help you

Comment: as greg says, TelecommunicationAddressUse.toString is *not* a simple name, it is a qualified name. Simple name cannot have '.' in them. The code should be trying a more open Name subclass. https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FName.html In your source, do you really need to qualify that toString ?

Comment: normally toString is a member function, while it is possible to qualify it with the class name, it is *very* uncommon to do so, hence revealing a slight bug in the tool you are using.